# Colored text with dcolumn

Tags: color, dcolumn

I want to typeset a table where certain numbers are going to appear red. In order to achieve the correct alignment I am using the dcolumn package. The problem is that the parsing that dcolumn does, prevents the correct appliance of color.

In the following example, in the third row, only the "1" appears red. The dot and the "32" appears black. Using `\textcolor` results in a syntactical mistake.

I tried using siunitx, but unfortunately, since I am producing programmatically hundreds of tables, the compilation time increased too much (more than a minute)

So the question is, how can you color a number belonging in a dcolumn?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{cd{2}}
note & 1.32\\
\color{red}note & 1.32 \\
\color{red}note & \color{red}1.32 \\
% note & 1.32\\
% \textcolor{red}{note} & 1.32 \\
% \textcolor{red}{note} & \textcolor{red}{1.32} \\  % results in a compilation error.
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can provide an approach by redefining the internal definition of the output.

The contents of a `dcolumn` is saved in two boxes and so you have to set the color before the output. Additional you must reset the color.

The example below provides a new command `\dcolcolor` to set the color of a cell defined by `dcolumn`. The usage is simple (`\dcolcolor` has one mandatory argument):

```
\dcolcolor{<color>}
```

Here the example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\DC@endright{$\hfil\egroup\@dcolcolor\box\z@\box\tw@\dcolreset}
\def\dcolcolor#1{\gdef\@dcolcolor{\color{#1}}}
\def\dcolreset{\dcolcolor{black}}
\dcolcolor{black}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{cd{2}}
note & 1.32\\
\color{red}note & 1.32 \\
note &\dcolcolor{red} 1.32 \\
 note & 1.32\\
 note & \dcolcolor{red}1.32\\
 \textcolor{red}{note} & 1.32 \\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I probably should have defined dcolumn to try harder to use the same typesetting state from the first box in any later boxes. Trouble would be knowing where to stop, colours, the math font family setup, sizes, user defined macros from `\newcommand`? Probably such a feature couldn't be done in a compatible way, but I add this comment should anyone be making an improved xxxdcolumn package and is looking for ideas... It would be nice (and probably possible) to make `\mathsf{\color{red} 123.456}` change the font and colour without messing up the alignment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the comment. I think `siunitx` can handle such a feature much easier by using the LaTeX3-Syntax. Maybe Joseph will provide this.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to also check out the formatting capabilities of the [siunitx](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/) package. The package provides, among many other things, a column type labeled `S`. With this package loaded instead of `dcolumn`, your MWE would like this this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{cS[table-format=1.2]}
note & 1.32\\
\color{red}note & 1.32 \\
\color{red}note & \color{red}1.32 \\
\textcolor{red}{note} & 1.32 \\
\textcolor{red}{note} & \textcolor{red}{1.32} \\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Observe that the package and its `S` column type have no problems with either `\color` or `\textcolor`.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I have already mentioned in my question, siunitx is not an option since it increases unacceptably the compilation time... But thanks anyway :)