# How to make \rowfont (from tabu package) overlay specification-aware (in beamer package)?

Tags: beamer, color, tabu, dcolumn

I have tables in a beamer presentation, and I would like to highlight table rows sequentially (not necessarily in row order) using overlay specifications. So I would like to be able to write code similar to the following:

```
\begin{tabular}
    \color<1>{red}
    Row 1  & Row 1 \\
    \color<2>{red}
    Row 2  & Row 2
\end{tabular}
```

with the effect that Row 1 is highlighted in red in the first slide and Row 2 is highlighted in the second slide.

I am using a `tabu` environment with `dcolumn` type columns. Here are some additional details about the findings I've made so far:

1. In [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42765/colored-text-with-dcolumn) I found code to define a command `dcolcolor` to be able to colour `dcolumn` text.
2. In order to colour the whole row's text without specifying each cell individually, I use `\rowfont` from `tabu`.
3. In order to make `\rowfont{\dcolcolor{...}}` overlay specification-aware, I try to follow the directions in section 9.6.1 of the beamer user guide.

However, I could not get it to work. So I tried using `only` on `\rowfont{...}` without trying to define a new, overlay specification-aware command, and I got an error. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\DC@endright{$\hfil\egroup\@dcolcolor\box\z@\box\tw@\dcolreset}
\def\dcolcolor#1{\gdef\@dcolcolor{\color{#1}}}
\def\dcolreset{\dcolcolor{black}}
\dcolcolor{black}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabu}{ld{2}d{2}}
% All of row 1 should be red on all slides
\rowfont{\color{red}\dcolcolor{red}}
Row 1 & 1.234 & 1.234 \
% All of row 2 should be red on second slide only
\only<2>{\rowfont{\color{red}\dcolcolor{red}}}
Row 2 & 2.345 & 2.345 \\
\end{tabu}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I compile, I get a couple of errors like

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\rowfont -&gt;\ifdim \baselineskip =\z@ \noalign
                                            \fi {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \tabu@row@...
l.28     \end{frame}
```

The output has two pages. The first page is correct, first row is highlighted (although the first column doesn't appear to be left-aligned). On the second page, the first row is highlighted as expected, but the second row only highlights the numbers, not the first column. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of output]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\rowfont{\only<2>{\color{red}\dcolcolor{red}}}
```

Comment: Thank you, a nice simple solution. Based on this answer I was able to create a new command `\newcommand<>{\highlighttext}{\only#1{\color{red}\dcolcolor{red}}}`. Usage would be `\rowfont{\highlighttext<1>}` above a row. However, note that `\newcommand<>{\highlightrow}{\rowfont{\only#1{\color{red}\dcolcolor{red}}}}` with usage `\highlightrow<1>` doesn't work.