# single cell bold with dcolumn

Tags: tables, dcolumn, boldmath

I am using `dcolumn` for a tabular, and I would like to have a single cell printed in bold face.
I know a similar question has been posed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84403/bold-text-with-dcolumn), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118458/decimals-in-table-dont-align-with-dcolumn-when-bolded), and the proposed solution is mentioned in the [documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/dcolumn.pdf/0) (page 4).

However, the proposed solution does not appear to work, at least in the minimal example below:

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,times,dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{b}{D{.}{.}{3}}
\newcolumntype{a}{D{.}{.}{6}}

% Bold version
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\boldmath\DC@{.}{.}{3}}c<{\DC@end}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\boldmath\DC@{.}{.}{6}}c<{\DC@end}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ab}
  1.134(2) & 1.3(1) \\
  \multicolumn{1}{A}{1.134(2)} & 1.3(1)
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with

```
pdflatex test.tex
```

gives

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@preamble ...hskip 1sp\d@llarbegin \boldmath \DC 
                                                  @{.}{.}{6}\array@row@rst \...
l.15   \multicolumn{1}{A}{1.134(2)}
                                    & 1.3(1)
```

Comment: You are missing `\makeatletter`

Comment: Off-topic: The `times` package borders on being obsolete. I suggest you replace `\usepackage{times}` with `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get no error if you properly segregate the code using `@`-commands between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, but the final result doesn't seem like you're expecting.

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,times,dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{b}{D{.}{.}{3}}
\newcolumntype{a}{D{.}{.}{6}}

% Bold version
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\boldmath\DC@{.}{.}{3}}c<{\DC@end}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\boldmath\DC@{.}{.}{6}}c<{\DC@end}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ab}
  1.134(2) & 1.3(1) \\
  \multicolumn{1}{A}{1.134(2)} & 1.3(1)
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The main cause for this is `times`, which has been obsolete for more than a quarter of a century. You get nothing better with `mathptmx`, which defines no bold math font.

The result is slightly better with NewTX.

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{b}{D{.}{.}{3}}
\newcolumntype{a}{D{.}{.}{6}}

% Bold version
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\boldmath\DC@{.}{.}{3}}c<{\DC@end}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\boldmath\DC@{.}{.}{6}}c<{\DC@end}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ab}
  1.134(2) & 1.3(1) \\
  \multicolumn{1}{A}{1.134(2)} & 1.3(1)
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You get the same result using `siunitx`, that provides many more features.

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.3(1),detect-weight] S[table-format=1.1(1)]}
  1.134(2) & 1.3(1) \\
  \bfseries 1.134(2) & 1.3(1)
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```