# Colouring text in table

Tags: tables, color

I have the following table:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn, bigdelim}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{5}{D{.}{.}{1}@{\hskip 7.5pt}}cc}
    \toprule
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    0.65 &  -2.26 & 0.71 & 0.97 & \rdelim\}{5}{14mm}[\parbox{20.5mm}{a}] \tabularnewline[5pt]
    1.00 &  -0.25 & 0.86 & 0.57 &\tabularnewline[5pt]
    -2.76 & -0.17 & 0.44 & 0.48 &\tabularnewline[5pt]
    -2.76 & -0.17 & 0.44 & 0.48 &\tabularnewline[5pt]
\midrule
   -2.96 & -0.17 & 0.42 & 0.48  &\rdelim\}{5}{14mm}[\parbox{20.5mm}{b}] \tabularnewline[5pt]
   -3.76 & -0.17 & 0.42 & 0.48 &\tabularnewline[5pt]
   -3.56 & -0.17 & 0.42 & 0.48 &\tabularnewline[5pt]
   -3.76 & -0.17 & 0.42 & 0.48 &\tabularnewline[5pt]
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

I would like to colour the text of some cells; e.g. all "0.42", how can I do that? I tried `\color{red}{0.42}` but it gave me some errors. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` (you can use the `article` class unless the problem is specific to a given class) and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem as opposed to figuring out exactly which packages are required.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, sorry for that, I edited it.

Comment: Fair point, I edited again and reframed the not-working problem into a question.

Comment: I thought you had it working in your code though?  Seems then that this problem is different than what you are encountering in your code. Anyway, you can wrap the `\color{}{}` within a `\multicolumn` so that it id not bothered by the `D` column type. But, this looses the alignment.

Comment: Isn't there an easier option with which I can just colour some letters? I am still confused why \color{}{} does not work here...

Comment: `\color{}{}` will work, although it should just be `\color{}` (as it takes only one parameter). I _think_ the problem is that `D` column type has an issue parsing that.

Comment: I see! I tried `\multirow{1}{*}{\color{red}{0.42}}` but it then destroys the brace alignment on the right, as you mentioned...

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42765/colored-text-with-dcolumn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with `S` columns (defined in `siunitx` pacakage), however your table design is not clear. You use 4 columns for numbers and one for big delimiter (curly brace), but define 5 columns for (decimal) numbers and two more `c` type columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell} % <---
\usepackage{bigdelim}

\usepackage{siunitx}            % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{S} @{\quad} c} % <---
    \toprule
{$x_1$} &{$x_2$}&{$x_3$}&{$x_4$}&  \\ % <---
    \midrule
0.65    & -2.26 & 0.71  & 0.97  &   $\rdelim\}{4}{3mm}[\,a]$   \\ % <---
 1.00   & -0.25 & 0.86  & 0.57  &   \\
-2.76   & -0.17 & 0.44  & 0.48  &   \\
-2.76   & -0.17 & 0.44  & 0.48  &   \\
    \midrule
-2.96   & -0.17 & \color{red}0.42       % <--- works fine
                        & 0.48  &   \\
-3.76   & -0.17 & 0.42  & 0.48  &   \\
-3.56   & -0.17 & 0.42  & 0.48  &   \\
-3.76   & -0.17 & 0.42  & 0.48  &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Yes, a thousand thanks!

Comment: @user192779 Remember to accept the answer by ticking off the V at the left side of the answer.